# aspx WebSite Maintenance - Missing .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

aspx newbie here - I've been asked to do some maintenance on an internal website.

Easy. It runs an apsx with a aspx.cs backend. This is downloaded and debugged from our SVN repo.

File - **default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dashboards.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Dashboards</title>
    <link href="redcss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <h1>Dashboards</h1>
        <div style="display: inline-block;"><span id ="spanDashList" runat ="server" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the whole unredacted aspx.

The matching .cs file is this one -

File - **default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
....

namespace Dashboards
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new 
            SqlConnection(" .... ");
            SqlDataAdapter da = ....

           * Populate the web control with a string generated from the database * 

            spanDashList.InnerHtml = str;

        }
    }
}
```

So I've debugged it (VS2017), fixed it, when it comes to deploying it (dump it into the file system of the web server)

**default.aspx.cs isn't there**

What I know

- The web server is correctly generating the page that I've debugged (that still needs fixing)
- I can edit default.aspx and dump 'Hello World' to my browser. I'm definitely looking at the correct file system on the server.
- Something's writing to spanDashList. If I remove it from the aspx, the browser errors

  Source Error:

  ```
  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

  Stack Trace: 

  [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
     Dashboards.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1564
     System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
     System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
  ```

Sorry if this is a bonkers one, I don't know where to look for the code that the server is running. I've tried looking on the whole hard drive of the machine for .cs files matching what I've fixed (or any .cs at all).

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .cs files don't get deployed to the web server. They are compiled (when you Build) into a DLL that should be in the bin folder underneath the web application's root folder.

When you deploy, you basically copy the ASPX files and the DLL to the web server (along with supporting files like web.config, scripts, images, stylesheets, etc.)

Comment: Is this always the case? I've got another part of the company internal website to manage where the .cs files do appear to be deployed raw. ie I edit the file, dump it onto the webserver and refresh the page to see my edits.

Comment: There used to be (maybe still is?) a .Net project type for Web sites as opposed to web applications. Web sites are "compiled on the fly" on the web server. Honestly I had forgotten about that until you asked this. Take a look at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd547590(v=vs.110)